# Windows Audit Mode -cannot login

Tags: windows, iso-image, windows-audit-mode

I am using this link to build a standard image of Windows 7:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523217%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

I got to the Windows Audit Mode point. For some odd reason, when my computer boots up in Audit mode it does NOT automatically login as Administrator. In fact it wants me to login, but none of my login usernames will work.

Screenshot:
[image]

I have hours of programs installed on this computer I am trying to build a standard Windows 7 image with. I really do not want to start over with a clean install.

Seeing that I cannot enter Windows Audit Mode, how can I get out of Windows Audit Mode and back into normal Windows Mode?

Rebooting computer and hitting F8 does not work.  This link is telling me that I need to use regedit. However I cannot log into Windows Audit Mode.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/how-to-exit-audit-mode-in-a-simple-step/9b8ef608-576a-4245-a294-9751bb680135

Comment: Its likely not logging into the Administrator account because its been disable.  Have you verified the Administrator account is enabled?

Comment: Yes it probably is disable. I didn't know I had to enable it and thought this was enabled automatically by Windows Audit Mode. Seeing I cannot login to Windows while in Audit mode, I cannot verify that the Administrator account is enable.

Comment: I would think that I could disable Audit Mode from the Recovery Disk?

Comment: Download Ultimate Boot CD and use the NTPasswd program on there to re-enable the Administrator account. Do not change the password of the user. Been there, wasted the hours lol. Why did you need Audit Mode? Customising default profile?